# Why edit input text with javascript don't update angularJs variable?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I want to load a text file and put the text of the file in an AngularJS variable by copying the file to a input text.

This js put the text on the input field:

```
document.getElementById('JSONFile').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);

function readFile(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var input = document.getElementById('jsontext');

    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        input.value = this.result;
    };
}
```

The input field is bound to an AngularJS variable:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="jsontext" id="jsontext" />
```

But the variable is updated only when I manually change something on text input, for test:

http://jsfiddle.net/uuuW6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you refer by `input_fiddle`, but I see you're just trying to bind a change handler to some input. The reason it does not work is that in AngularJS, the data changes are treated by the [digest loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) via [watches](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

To change data within a context which is not bounded to a scope, you can either call `$apply` to active a digest cycle (or wrap that code with an apply function), or just use the classic, Angulary way, and bind the change handler via a directive, e.g.:

```js
$scope.$apply(function () {
    input.value = this.result;
});
```

#### Further reading

- *[$watch How the $apply Runs a $digest](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/)* on Angular Tips

Comment: I just want to say that I change the value of the input with the javascript `input.value = this.result;`. I changed the title.
Did you miss the url links to "digest loop" and "watches"?

Comment: i don't know where is that code sitting, but you should read a bit more about how angular works and get familiarized with it. [here's a good tutorial as a starting point](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/).